# The object of type 'SpriteRenderer' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my game's SpriteRenderer I get this error The object of type 'SpriteRenderer' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it resolved the error message by declaring the
sprite != null following an orientation from here

```
public void DestroyEnemy(){
    if (sprite != null)
    {
    sprite.enabled = false;
    capsule.enabled = false;
    smoke.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

when the enemy is destroyed the smoke effect and called only once on the next enemy does not happen anymore

```
if(other.CompareTag("EnemyHead")){
        player.Impulse();
        enemy.DestroyEnemy();
        Destroy(other.transform.parent.gameObject, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

please help me how do I solve this thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you are checking if it is null even though the variable is destroyed. You should add a different variable that changes when the enemy is destroyed and check for that variable to be null/0.

Comment: could you give me an example please

Comment: I'll post it in an answer.

Comment: Have you tried rather using [`if(sprite)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)? See [Custom == operator](https://blogs.unity3d.com/es/2014/05/16/custom-operator-should-we-keep-it/)

Answer (score -1):

Change the last code block/script you showed us to this:

```cs
public bool destroyed = false;
if(other.CompareTag("EnemyHead")){
        player.Impulse();
        enemy.DestroyEnemy();
        destroyed = true;
        Destroy(other.transform.parent.gameObject, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

And change the first script to:

```cs
public GameObject obj;
bool destroyed = false;

void Update(){
    destroyed = obj.GetComponent<theScriptUpAbove’sName>().destroyed;
}
public void DestroyEnemy(){
    if (!destroyed)
    {
    sprite.enabled = false;
    capsule.enabled = false;
    smoke.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

These will work assuming that both methods are in the same script. Once the enemy is destroyed, it will not execute the if statement. So when the enemy is alive, the code in block 2, line 4 will be executed.

Comment: ok friend Ken thanks for helping, sorry for my lack of clarity is there are two different scipts the first block belongs to the script of the object related to the player, the second block refers to the enemy's script, what is happening is that the DestroyEneny() function is being called only once when defeating the first enemy in the other enemies, the DestroyEnemy() function no longer works. I still couldn't get it to work but thanks to your help

Comment: You can always use objectVariable.GetComponent<scriptName>.variableName = value                                      If you don’t know what I mean, then I updated my answer to show you what. (Put the first scripts object into the obj variable in the editor. And change ‘theScriptAbove’sName’ to the script above’s name.